# A RenderFlex overflowed by 658 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

inside Scaffold i  used this line of code to avoid RenderFlex overflowed error on the bottom, but  nothing changed in my page,shows

> BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 658 PIXELS

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Please take a look,  i did everything i can and i won't make it .
here is the `PuzzleDetailsPage`:

[image: DevTools]

```
class PuzzleDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  PuzzleDetailsPage(
      {this.includeMarkAsDoneButton = true,
      required this.id,
      required this.imageUrl});

  final bool includeMarkAsDoneButton;
  final String id;
  final String imageUrl;

  static int count = 0;

  final Stream newsStream =
      Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (_) => count++);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
              width: size.width,
              height: size.height,
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                    Image.asset('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
                errorWidget: (context, url, dynamic e) => Icon(Icons.error),
              )),
          _buildBody(context, size)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _tips() {
    List<Widget> _tips = <Widget>[];

    return _tips;
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, Size size) {
    newsStream
        .map((e) {
          count = e as int;
          print(count);
          return 'stuff $e';
        })
        .take(5)
        .forEach((e) {
          print(e);
        });
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.6),
      width: size.width,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: [
              _buildImage(context, size),
              Positioned(
                  top: 100,
                  left: 100,
                  child: Text(
                    'tips',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                  ))
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: smallPadding),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                _buildButton(size, context),
                _buildBoard(context, size)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBoard(BuildContext context, Size size) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFcec89f),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                  spreadRadius: 5,
                  blurRadius: 5,
                  offset: Offset(0, 6)),
            ],
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.width / 8),
          width: size.width / 3,
          height: size.width / 3,
          child: ListView(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: verySmallPadding, bottom: 0.0),
            children: [
              _buildRankItem(context, size),
              _buildRankItem(context, size),
              _buildRankItem(context, size),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: size.width / 10, left: size.width / 3 - 50),
            width: size.width / 12,
            height: size.width / 12,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/icons/bookmark.svg',
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ))
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRankItem(BuildContext context, Size size) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: mediumPadding),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: size.width / 15,
            width: size.width / 15,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 60,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/bg/waifu.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            '00:00',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: mediumText,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildButton(Size size, BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.width / 8),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: size.width / 2,
              height: size.width / 2,
              child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/controller.svg'),
            ),
            Container(
              width: size.width / 2,
              height: size.width / 2,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.width / 5),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  MyCircleButton(
                    width: size.width / 6,
                    text: 'X',
                    press: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context, true);
                    },
                  ),
                  MyCircleButton(
                    width: size.width / 6,
                    text: 'O',
                    press: () async {
                      Uint8List bytes =
                          await ImageUtil.networkImageToBase64(imageUrl);
                      await startGame(context, bytes);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildImage(BuildContext context, Size size) {
    return Hero(
      tag: '$id',
      child: Transform(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        transform: Matrix4.skewX(-0.05),
        child: Container(
          height: size.height * 0.6,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFFF0000), width: 0.5),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 5,
                    offset: Offset(10, -6)),
              ]),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: veryBigPadding * 2, left: bigPadding, right: bigPadding),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              imageUrl: imageUrl,
              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                  Image.asset('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
              errorWidget: (context, url, dynamic e) => Icon(Icons.error),
            ),

            // Image.memory(
            //   bytes,
            //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
            // ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> startGame(BuildContext context, Uint8List bytes) async {
    await Navigator.push<void>(
        context,
        MyLoadingRoute<void>(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            builder: (context) =>
                PuzzlePlayPage(MediaQuery.of(context).size, bytes, 3)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a SafeArea widget by wrapping another widget with SafeArea. It adds minimum padding and helps avoid system intrusions. You can check out the Flutter documentation on how to appropriately add it to your code: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html#:~:text=SafeArea%20class%20Null%20safety,the%20top%20of%20the%20screen.

Answer (score 1):

i used to wrap my column with

> SingleChildScrollView

```
return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.6),
      height: size.height,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: [
                _buildImage(context, size),
                Positioned(
                    top: 100,
                    left: 100,
                    child: Text(
                      'tips',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                    ))
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: smallPadding),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  _buildButton(size, context),
                  _buildBoard(context, size)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```